# Hiding calculations in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i'm pretty new to coding and stuffs.. so i have website where it has a mortgage calculator, and i have trouble with hiding the calculations (I don't want the calculations to be visible)

I've tried using <!--- and ---> but it didn't work out,

Do anyone have suggestions?

```html
<table class="table" style="line-height:1.5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" valign="top" style="font-family:Avenir;">Harga Rumah</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <span id="hasil_harga_rumah">0</span> - Rp <span id="hasil_uang_muka">0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <strong><span id="pinjaman">0</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" valign="top" style="font-family:Avenir;">Total Kredit</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <span class="hasil_pinjaman">0</span> + (Rp <span class="hasil_pinjaman">0</span> * <span id="hasil_margin">0</span>% * <span class="hasil_tenor">0</span> tahun)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <strong><span id="total_pinjaman">0</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" valign="top" style="font-family:Avenir;">Cicilan / bulan </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <span id="hasil_total_pinjaman">0</span> / <span class="hasil_tenor">0</span> / 12 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = Rp <strong><span id="cicilan_bulanan">0</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" valign="top" style="font-family:Avenir;">Persentase Cicilan</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family:Avenir;"> = <strong><span id="persentase_cicilan">0</span> %</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-family:Avenir;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just to be clear, do you want any specific column to hide or calculation to hide ? or the whole table? and once you hide them when they will unhide?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You only provided us with some HTML. Where is the JS? We need a little more context.

Comment: you could use [visibility](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-or-show-html-elements-using-visibility-property-in-javascript/) to hide/show elements

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the `display="none"` style property?
For example on a `<div>` tag:

```
<div style="display: none">
... calculator stuff...
</div>
```

If you can you should try using a Cascading Stylesheet instead of adding style attributes on html tags:
see for example the 'External CSS' part of https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp .
And here is some additional info on the CSS `display` property: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp